# How to add and update json array elements using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-hooks, state

I defined a state with null array, Then that array will contain firstname, lastname etc..based on entry in text field. ***I need to add the prop if not present and update the prop if present.*** I need to do validation in save based on that. I tried with below code, but that not works.

```
const [signerData, setSignerData] = useState([]);

const newItems = [...signerData];
newItems["firstName"] = inputValue;
setSignerData({ newItems });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a little more code, place the complete example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you would need an object instead of an array. Array doesn't allow you to have keys, only values. The below code would work.

```html
const [signerData, setSignerData] = useState({});

setSignerData({ ...signerData, firstName: inputValue });
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `newItems["firstName"] = inputValue` is mutating and should not be done this way.

Comment: Thank you so much. Working fine now with this implementation.